# The important question on how to download Magento (for 1.9.x.x) is broken

Tags: discussion

This is probably one of the more important question on Magento Stack Exchange:

[How to download magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28582/how-to-download-magento)

The top 3 answer appear to no longer be true, at least for Magento 1.9.x.x. Am I mistaken? How should we handle this? Can we edit one or more of existing answers substantially to reflect the changes? Should I ask a new question or would that be a dupe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a recurring discussion on StackOverflow and the whole StackExchange network and I don't think there is a definite official answer.

### Some threads on Meta.SE

- [How do we encourage edits to obsolete/out of date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261817/how-do-we-encourage-edits-to-obsolete-out-of-date-answers)
- [How to deal with obsolete answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11705/how-to-deal-with-obsolete-answers)

### Summary

- if obsolete answers can be easily fixed without changing them completely (like replace a dead link), edit the answer
- otherwise downvote and add a comment to notify the author and other readers (If I am 100% sure that the answer is not useful anymore you could even edit a notice into the answer itself).
- add a new up-to-date answer if necessary

In case of the linked question [How to download magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/28582/how-to-download-magento)
I already downvoted and commented three of the answers in the past for that very reason. The top voted answer by @FabianBlechschmidt at least works partially: the `curl` method, not the direct link. So comment and/or edit would be appropiate. If you have a completely different solution, feel free to add a new answer.

And yes, a new question would be a duplicate.